# useState invalid hook call in function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I've tried for the past few days now to try and figure out why I keep getting this error-

> react-dom.development.js:16227 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid
> hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function
> component.

**useState Component**

```
import { useState } from 'react';

async function CreateMeta() {
  const { test, setTest } = useState();
}
export default CreateMeta;
```

**Main Component**

```
import CreateMeta from "./createmeta.js";

const Minter = (props) => {
  const onPressed = async () => {
    await CreateMeta();  
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onPressed}>Test</Button>
    </>
  )
}

export default Minter;
```

Which is then called in other components -

```
return (
  <>
    <Minter />
  </>
)
```

I've tried several suggestions but nothing works and my code seems to be correct. Im able to useState in some of my other components only if it's set in the same component.

Whenever I try calling a useState component instead of rendering in the return, I get the invalid hook error. Same happens with other "use" Hooks. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you want to call a method that creates a state element of a hook that returns nothing? Yo are also not passing any `props` to the `Minter` component btw...

Comment: @FerToasted in the CreateMeta component, I use hooks to get data to run some functions, and when it's complete, the onPressed function is suppose to execute the next line. I simplified my code though because the error is happening even with that little bit of code.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how it could work with an api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Main issue:**

React hooks can be used only inside body of rendering function (Functional Component). In your example "useState" is called inside click handler, so it will not work.

To fix this error you should move 'useState' directly into some rendering function body or into some hook.

**My guess solution:**

I'm not 100% sure what you need in your exact case, but may guess:

1. Rename function `CreateMeta` to be `useCreateMeta` (so it will be a hook) and don't make it async.
2. Inside this hook, apart state (pay attention - use square brackets with useState), define a callback with all expected async logic inside and return this callback from this hook:

```js
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

function useCreateMeta() {
 const [test, setTest] = useState(); // <-- square brackets here (array, not object)
 const createMeta = useCallback(async () => {
    // do whatever you need inside, e.g.:
    // set state:
    setTest('creating meta...');
    // Do some async things:
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
      setTest('meta created');
      resolve();
    }, 1000));
 }, []);
 return {createMeta};
}

export default useCreateMeta;
```

3. Call this hook right inside `Minter` components like this:

```js
function Minter () {
  // ...
  const {createMeta} = useCreateMeta();
  const onPressed = async () => {
    await createMeta();  
  };
  // ...
}
```

Example of the code see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cookies-9be20n

Comment: thanks, this seems to be working for my situation. I am testing things more but so far this solution works!

Comment: I ran into an issue where state values that are changed by other components (Im using "use-between" module), isnt reflecting the changes in the `useCreateMeta callback` but the changes do show up in `function useCreateMeta()` . Any ideas?

Comment: @730wavy need an example, hard to tell without the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is what it says. You cannot invoke hooks outside of a component.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

async function CreateMeta() {
 const { test, setTest } = useState();
}
export default CreateMeta;
```

You code does not show a component. Just a function...

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const CreateMeta = (props) => {
 const { test, setTest } = useState();
}
```

**EDIT1:**

I am doing it this way:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { getUser } from "./api";

export const MainMenu = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  function handleClick(event) {
    //this would replace async
    getUser(10).then((response) => {
      setUser(response.data);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Klick me</button>
      {user && <div>{user.firstname}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

API

```
import { axios } from "../services/api"

export const getUser = (userId) => {
    return axios.get("/url",{userId : userId }); //this will returns a promise
}
```

Or you can await and async

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { getUser } from "./api";

export const MainMenu = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const handleClick = async (event) => {
    const response = await getUser(10);
    setUser(response.data);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Klick me</button>
      {user && <div>{user.firstname}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

API

```
import { axios } from "../services/api"

export const getUser = async (userId) => {
    const response = await axios.get("/url",{userId : userId }); //this will returns a promise
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried it that way as well and still received the same error - `export const CreateMeta = async (props) => {` :(

Comment: Remove the async. A component cannot be async. Maybe you try to tell what your intensions are.

Comment: Im using the async because I have api calls and functions that need to be executed in order one after another

Answer (score 0):

You should define useState hook like below

```
import { useState } from 'react';

async function CreateMeta() {
 const [ test, setTest ] = useState();
}
export default CreateMeta;
```

and It will work.

Comment: hi if you're referring to the { } vs [ ], it still gives me the same error

Comment: You should definitely use square brackets instead of curly braces, but this is far from the only problem in your code.

Comment: ok noted. what other problems are you referring to?

Comment: I do not see the api calls. If you post more code I would check it to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is `CreateMeta` supposed to be a React component? Components cannot be async and cannot be called (like you do in `onPressed`).
It's a bit unclear to me what you are trying to do, but you should probably have your state in the `Minter` component and the `onPressed` callback can change the state.